# REST API to post to my users' WordPress website

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

So, I have a website where I am allow users to aggregate certain settings into readable html pages that can be emailed or copied in html to be shared elsewhere.

What I would like to do now is use REST API in order to allow users to post this content **directly** to their WordPress blogs (independently hosted or on wordpress.com). From my research, REST API is the best way to go about doing this. However, I cannot seem to find any reliable resources on how this is to be exactly implemented or achieved (or if it is 100% entirely possible).

I'm hoping there are one or two people who have had experience with this sort of thing and who can provide me with some guidance!

Comment: WordPress has a [REST API](https://developer.wordpress.com/docs/api/), which lets you [create a post](https://developer.wordpress.com/docs/api/1.1/post/sites/%24site/posts/new/).

Answer (score 0):

There is no standard REST interface to WordPress. However, WordPress does have an XMLRPC interface to post, edit, and otherwise manage content. Information on this interface is available in the WordPress Codex at:

https://codex.wordpress.org/XML-RPC_WordPress_API